# 'Unspecified error' message when copy a file from Windows Sandbox

Tags: windows, windows-10, copy-paste, windows-sandbox

I get this message randomly when I copy a file from Windows Sandbox using Copy/Paste shortcuts.

[image]

The error has no specific reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of try and error, I found out that if you use the Copy/Paste shortcuts to copy from Windows Sandbox to the host, you shouldn't copy anything else to the ClipBoard until the copy is done. Doing so will cause the copy operation to fail with that error message.

Answer (score 0):

It's true, even if you connect to a remote machine with the Sandbox on it. I connect via RDP to a remote device which has the sandbox then running on it, and even *if you copy something on the local device,* not in any way to do with the remote machine OR the sandbox, it still errors. Makes me wonder if it actually copies through the local device or something.
If you do do this - you can start the copy, then close the remote session and do what you need to do, and reconnect closer to when it's done, if needed. Just don't copy anything while the RDP session is open!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).